# PostreSql: ERROR: column referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

What might possibly gone wrong?

```
ERROR: column "parameter_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
1 statement failed.
```

So i created 2 tables(**parameters** and **periods**) with the commands;

```
create table parameters(
  parameter_id serial primary key,
  temperature real,
  feels_good_temperature int,
  humidity int,
  max_uv_index int
);
```

and

```
create table periods(
  period_id serial primary key,
  time_stamp text
);
```

...and now i want to have a column, `fk_paramter_id` in `periods` table, as a foreign key to the `parameters` table

I tried achieving it with;

```
ALTER TABLE periods 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_parameter_id FOREIGN KEY (parameter_id) 
REFERENCES parameters(parameter_id);
```

Comment: But periods has no column parameter_id... The columns must exist before you add the fk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to create and populate the column:

```
ALTER TABLE periods ADD parameter_id integer;
```

Then use `UPDATE`s to set the correct values.

Now you can define the constraint.

Note: the constraint (`fk_paramter_id`) is *not* a column; it is *defined on a column* (`parameter_id`).